# Converting MP4 to WAV

Tags: java, audio, audio-streaming, audio-converter

I'm creating a small audio player in Java and can play certain formats fine (such as WAV). I've discovered that this is because `javax.sound` does not support MP4. From what I've read though, converting from MP4 to WAV is lossless so I believe that this shouldn't be that difficult. I know there are plenty of 3rd party libraries out there that can do this, but I'm not interested in downloaded one for something that should be fairly straightforward. I've looked into the specific ISO's for each to try to understand how the data is stored to be able to just create a `BufferedReader` and `BufferedWritter` to see if I could manually convert it, but I was unable to find the information I was looking for. What would be a way to go about doing this in pure Java 1.7.0 (I know JavaFX has a MediaPlayer, but unfortunately I cannot use 1.8.0).

Or if anyone knows where I can find specific container information for each (such as the header size/information, data, ACK/NACK, etc.) that compose both MP4 and WAV.

Comment: What makes you think that this is remotely straightforward?  This is actually extremely complicated.  The codecs likely in use in your MP4 file all have decades of research behind them.  Use an existing codec.  Better yet, use FFmpeg and let it do all the work for you.  I don't understand why you think you can't use an existing library.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is nothing straight forward about MP4 to wav. Fist off, MP4 is a container not a codec. So your MP4 may contain wav, mp3, aac, AC3, DD+, etc. And all of these formats will required a different decoder to 'convert' to raw PCM.

Comment: Wouldn't there still be a header in my MP4 container that would say where the wav/mp3/aac are inside of it?

Comment: The elementary stream will be broken into many chunks, and each chunk can be found by parsing the 'stco' atom.

Comment: Thanks! I was able to use that to get the mp3 and then convert that to PCM.